# The DIV is not auto-adjusting its height after a certain limit. Please see

Tags: html, height

The following is the HTML code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

   <head>
     <title>Gallery</title>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="design.css" />
   </head>
   <body>

  <div id="wrapper">



     <div id="title">
     <p id="title_font">
     NAVNEET<br />
     KHARE
     </p>
     </div>



   <div id="flickr">

        <!-- Content will go here -->

   </div>

   <div class="page_header">
     GALLERY
   </div>

    <?php 
     include ("navig.html");
    ?> 
   </div>      

   </body>


</html>
```

And here goes the CSS :

@

```
charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
*{margin:0px; padding:0px; border:0px; line-height: 100%; font-size: 100%;}

html {height:auto;width:auto;}
body {background-color:#000;width:100%;height:auto;}
#wrapper {position:absolute;width:870px;min-height:100%;background-color:#191919;left:50%;margin-left:-435px;height:auto;}
#title {position:absolute;left:1%;}
#title_font {color:#FFF;font-size:60px;line-height:100%;}
#navig {position:absolute;width:200px;right:-4%;top:400px;}
.nav {position:absolute;background-color:#666;height:20px;width:150px;display:block;text-decoration: none;text-align: center;color:white;
-moz-transition-property:-moz-transform 1s;
-moz-transition-duration:3s;
-moz-transition-timing-function:cubic-bezier(0, 1, 0, 1);
-o-transition-property:-moz-transform 1s;
-o-transition-duration:3s;
-o-transition-timing-function:cubic-bezier(0,1,0,1);
-webkit-transition-property:-moz-transform 1s;
-webkit-transition-duration:3s;
-webkit-transition-timing-function:cubic-bezier(0,1,0,1);
}

.nav:hover
 { 
   background-color : #A0050A;
  -moz-transform:translate(-20px,0px);
  -o-transform:translate(-20px,0px);
  -webkit-transform:translate(-20px,0px);

 }


#front_image {position:absolute;top:150px;left:70px;padding-bottom:30px;}

#chat {position:absolute;top:150px;left:70px;padding-bottom:30px;}

#grooveshark {position:absolute;top:150px;left:70px;padding-bottom:30px;}

#comment_box {position:absolute;top:150px;left:70px;padding-bottom:30px;}

#flickr {position:absolute;top:150px;left:12px;height:600px;width:677px;background-color:white;}

#hide {position:absolute;width:577px;height:30px;background-color:#191919;top:615px;left:70px;z-index:2;}
.page_header {position:absolute;top:250px;right:2%;color:#BD060B;font-size:xx-large;text-align:center;border-style:solid;border-color:#BD060B;border-width:medium;width:150px;word-wrap:normal;word-spacing:5px;padding:2px;}
```

The problem is, as you can see, I've made the div "flickr" to be of size of 600 px (heightwise) and thus, I was expecting the wrapper div to expand accordingly to contain all the children divs. But the result isn't quite so. I am attaching a picture below to show what is the result that I am getting. I've used a red arrow to show the problem :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0W4K.jpg

It'd be really great if someone could highlight my mistake! Thanks a bunch in advance!

Comment: way too much absolute positioning.

Comment: @Scott 

Is something wrong with that? I thought absolute positioning can keep things more "bound" together in the context of parent-child containing behavior.

Comment: Can someone please explain as to why it's not advisable to use absolute positioning? Is there a semantic reason to that or a logical one?

Comment: When you absolute position something you are telling that element to configure itself based on the browser window (or parent element). So, you remove its ability to adjust itself dynamically. What you want here is a div which adjusts dynamically, but you want it positioned absolutely. Those two are pretty much mutually exclusive. Absolute positioning is something you should use sparingly. And my preference is to always use it in relation to a parent element. So, while objects may be positioned within the page, they aren't positioned based on the window itself.

Comment: Thanks for your response, @Scott. I think I get it now.What I've understood is that because I was using absolute positioning, the browser was not reserving any space for the elements inside the div and thus, it did not know how vertically long the containing div should be. Thank you for your input, Scott! Correct me if I am still missing something :P

Answer (score 1):

Do not use position absolute every where. Use this code It will work for you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
 <title>Gallery</title>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
<style>charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
 *{margin:0; padding:0; border:0; }

 body {background-color:#000;}
 #wrapper {position:absolute;width:870px;min-height:100%;background-color:#191919;left:50%;margin-left:-435px;height:auto;}
#title {}
#title_font {color:#FFF;font-size:60px;line-height:100%;}
  #navig {position:absolute;width:200px;right:-4%;top:400px;}
.nav {position:absolute;background-color:#666;height:20px;width:150px;display:block;text-decoration: none;text-align: center;color:white;
}

.nav:hover
 { 
   background-color : #A0050A;

 }


#front_image {position:absolute;top:150px;left:70px;padding-bottom:30px;}

#chat {position:absolute;top:150px;left:70px;padding-bottom:30px;}

#grooveshark {position:absolute;top:150px;left:70px;padding-bottom:30px;}

#comment_box {position:absolute;top:150px;left:70px;padding-bottom:30px;}

#flickr {height:600px;width:677px;background-color:white;}

#hide {position:absolute;width:577px;height:30px;background-color:#191919;top:615px;left:70px;z-index:2;}
.page_header {position:absolute;top:250px;right:2%;color:#BD060B;font-size:xx-large;text-align:center;border-style:solid;border-color:#BD060B;border-width:medium;width:150px;word-wrap:normal;word-spacing:5px;padding:2px;}</style>
   </head>
   <body>

  <div id="wrapper">



     <div id="title">
 <p id="title_font">
 NAVNEET<br />
 KHARE
 </p>
 </div>



   <div id="flickr">

    <!-- Content will go here -->

   </div>

   <div class="page_header">
 GALLERY
   </div>

    <?php 
     include ("navig.html");
    ?> 
   </div>      

   </body>


</html>
```

Comment: This doesn't actually solve my problem.... If I do what you did, how will I still be able to alter the position of the flickr div, if, its width was less than what I've set it to be right now? Static members are not affected by left, right etc parameters as far as I know. Correct me if I am wrong please.